# unable to display OS name in C using utsname

Tags: c, operating-system, cygwin, shared-libraries

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE
#include <sys/utsname.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/times.h>
#include <sched.h>

int main(void) {
    puts("!!!Hello World!!!"); /* prints !!!Hello World!!! */

    struct utsname uts;
    struct tms time;

    //obtaining cpu type and model
    execlp("start","starting", NULL);
    /*
    int outfd = open("starting.txt", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC, 0644);
    if(!outfd) {
            perror("open");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    dup2(outfd, 1);
    close(outfd);*/
    if (uname(&uts) < 0)
        perror("uname() error");
    else {
        printf("Sysname:  %s\n", uts.sysname);
        printf("Nodename: %s\n", uts.nodename);
        printf("Release:  %s\n", uts.release);
        printf("Version:  %s\n", uts.version);
        printf("Machine:  %s\n", uts.machine);
    }
    puts("done");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I have been trying to get the OS version using uts but for some reason I can't seem to obtain it, instead I am getting the output:

```
!!!Hello World!!!
Sysname:  CYGWIN_NT-10.0-18363
Nodename: LAPTOP-K1QSQFS4
Release:  3.3.6-341.x86_64
Version:  2022-09-05 11:15 UTC
Machine:  x86_64
done
```

When I want it to output my Host OS Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using Cygwin. If you look at the relevant [part of the source of its `uname()` function](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=newlib-cygwin.git;a=blob;f=winsup/cygwin/uname.cc;h=136b1c57ac35d86dc5cde77638882f94d5019ab0;hb=HEAD#l114), you see:

```c
/* Cygwin "version" aka build date */
strcpy (name->version, cygwin_version.dll_build_date);
```

So getting a date for the version is perfectly normal, intended behavior in the cygwin environment.

Comment: Your title mentions OS name, but the text of your question was about version so that's what I went with.

Comment: got it, I was trying to get the OS of the host using a library from it though. is there an api call that I should look into instead?

Comment: You mean the underlying Windows version that cygwin is running on top of? Probably some Win32 call (I think I saw something relevant in the uname source I liked), but I'm not sure if cygwin provides access to those functions.